# Relative directories in code run by the designer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm writing a program in WPF and the problem I'm having is that the code that gets run in my program while in the VS designer loads an SQLite database. If the file doesn't exist the code attempts to create a blank database.

While all this code works perfectly during runtime. In the designer, the relative path to the database file is different, 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE. Since the program doesn't have access to write to this folder then an exception is thrown which prevents me from using the designer.

If I change my program to use a absolute path to the database and everything works fine. The designer even reads the database and initialises the interface with data from it.

Is there anyway to change the working directory that the visual studio designer uses to evaluate the code so that I can continue using a relative path. Alternatively, some way to get the location of the exe rather than the working directory. Everything I've tried returns VS's IDE folder.

Answer (score 0):

Is the db file under your project folder and included in the project? It sounds like you have a file referenced outside of the project 'cone'. This issue will go away if you add the file directly to the project, or use a link to reference it, and then base your pathing off of that copy or link.

Comment: Yes, it is added to the project and set to copy to the output directory. It is in Data\data.s3db. When I build the solution, the file and folder are copied to the output directory. In my connection string I then have Data Source=Data\\data.s3db. I've commented out the code that tried to create it if it doesn't exist and now I just get couldn't open the database file.

Comment: @Android - So your reference path is always 'Data\data.s3db'?